# Bound of norm of ordered numbers

Tags: normed-spaces, order-statistics

Suppose we have two sets of real numbers $x$ and $y$ each with $n$ elements. Suppose I order the sets such that $x_{(1)} \geq x_{(2)} \geq x_{(3)} \geq ... \geq x_{(n)}$ and  $y_{(1)} \geq y_{(2)} \geq y_{(3)} \geq ... \geq y_{(n)}$. I have been struggling to show that:

$|x_{(k)} - y_{(k)}| \leq ||x-y||_2$

In other words:

$|x_{(k)} - y_{(k)}| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2}$

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can prove a much stronger inequality: 
$$
||\tilde{x} - \tilde{y}||^2\le ||{x} - {y}||^2,
$$
where $\tilde x$ and $\tilde y$ are the order statistics vectors. Just expand the squares and use [the rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).